# What does dvi, int, sto, flq etc. stand for in setupapi.dev.log-files?

Tags: windows, log-files, drivers

When debugging my .inf-file I have ended up reading the setupapi.dev.log-file (/windows/inf/) to find out what is going wrong. The Microsoft generated log-file contains the following abbreviations which I want to find out what they stand for:

- dvi
- inf
- sto
- idb
- flq
- ump
- ndv
- sig
- cpy

I can guess that cpy stands for copy and sig for signature. But the others? I'm just curious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find that information in the [Format of a Text Log Section Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544958.aspx) section of MSDN.

Random selection:

dvi: Device installation

flq: Manage file queues

inf: Manage INF files

ndv: New device wizard